# How to specify a hashed shard key using mongoengine?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I currently have a document that looks something like:

```
class Document(db.Document):
   item1 = db.StringField()
   item2 = db.StringField()
```

I would like to define the shard key within mongoengine like [this](https://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/guide/defining-documents.html#shard-keys). However, I would like define the shard key as a [hashed shard key](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/shard-collection-with-a-hashed-shard-key/) on the document id. Is it possible to do this within mongoengine? If so, could you steer me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer**

After searching the docs and code behind it seems this feature is unsupported in mongoengine.

**Possible Work Around**

MongoDB uses a hashed index behind the scenes when creating a hashed shard key.

1. Manually create a hashed index on the field using mongo shell command.

   `db.collection.createIndex( { fieldName: "hashed" } )`
2. Find the name of the newly created index by running:

   `db.collection.getIndexes()`
3. In mongoengine use the name of the index as the shard key field:

   ```
   class Document(db.Document):
       item1 = db.stringField()
       item2 = db.StringField()

       meta = {
           'shard_key': ('_indexName_')
       }
   ```

Comment: I suspected I'd have to do something like this. Thanks for the help!